# Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringBootApplication'

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to java springboot.. I got a new laptop and i installed all the software and started with spring.io as soon as i import im getting this error "Cannot resolve symbol 'SpringBootApplication'" i havent changed anything yet.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Receive</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Receive</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Tried reimporting maven/cleared cache nothing seems to be working. Please help

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "as soon as i import " An IDE (which IDE then)? Does it work when you run `mvn clean install` from the command line ?

Comment: I'm using intelliJ 2020.03.03 community edition

Comment: Great, so does it work from the command line?

Comment: Tried mvn clean install it doesnt work

Comment: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.3.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent

Answer (score 1):

Try this
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate And Restart

Answer (score 0):

can you try `mvn clean install -U` it will force update dependencies

Comment: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.3.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvab

Comment: can you share little more error message details,

Comment: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.volvo:Receive:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer faile
d for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.3.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10

Answer (score 0):

If that's the whole pom, you didn't close the project tag.
Add `</project>` below `</build>` and try to load maven changes to update dependencies.

Comment: its just not copied. ITs failing to update dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Change `https` in this line:

```
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
```

to `http`